# DatabaseExists failing SQLite operations (.NET 4.0, EF 4.4)

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm using .NET 4.0 and Entity Framework 4.4

I've had code that has worked for years suddenly seize up on me - and I'm thoroughly stymied as to why.  I've distilled the problem code to a very simple sequence.  Note that the code behavior doesn't change if I create the physical file on disk; it's simply not involved in the problem.

```
string sDatabaseFilename = @"c:\users\bob\database.sqlite";
//System.IO.File.Create(sDatabaseFilename).Close();
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection cConnection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("DataSource=" + sDatabaseFilename);
System.Data.Entity.DbContext dbContext = new System.Data.Entity.DbContext(cConnection, false);
System.Data.Entity.Database dDatabase = dbContext.Database;

dDatabase.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

app.config data provider:

```
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
```

Any attempts to touch dDatabase (e.g. ExecuteSqlCommand as above) or access dbContext.ObjectContext results in

```
System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException occurred
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=DatabaseExists is not supported by the provider.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.DbDatabaseExists(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
  InnerException:
```

I had this working with the v1.0.88 SQLite stuff, then it stopped working (I was fooling with some HTML scraping in a separate project in the same solution).  I've upgraded to SQLite v1.0.98 to try to clear the problem, but without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out the problem, but I did end up working around it.

The workaround was to create a new solution and build the project again from the original source files.  I first created a barebones solution to figure out what I needed in order to make it work, then built out from there.

Things that did not fix the problem:

1. Upgrading the broken solution to EF 6.0 and the appropriate SQLite through NuGet.
2. Matching the broken solution's app.config and packages.config files to the barebones solution.
3. Trying to "clean up" the project files in the broken solution by removing sections that didn't match the barebones solution.

Whatever it is that is causing the problem with my old solution is somewhere in the project files, but I never found out what it was.  Note that this is all with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The cause of the problem was pilot error.  Somehow I had changed the settings on my Visual Studio Exceptions.  I was running such that no exception would trip the debugger, so this exception didn't pop up.  But when I changed over to trying to spot any exception, a bunch of exceptions like this one started showing up.  I didn't connect the dots.

Apparently, this particularly exception is innocuous for my situation and can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is EF try to make initialize the db.
Before use context set to null the initializer.

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
```